# What are the activities involved in Commerce Content Migration?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, migration

I am in the process of analyzing the option of migrating the existing commerce data into Sitecore Commerce, what are the activities are involved in that ?

As far i know,

a. Analyze existing Commerce Structure
b. Document the Existing Category, Product Definitions

c. Design new Category, Product, Property Definitions
d. Create new Category, Product, Property Definitions
e. Review the implementation
f. Create sample Products
g. Organize Existing Products Data for Import
h. Import existing Products into Commerce system
i. Review the Data Import

Can someone add if anything to be considered.

Comment: can you specify what one is your existing commerce system?